# How to get Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat NuGet packages

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to follow a xamarin tutorial on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

But the tutorial requires that my project have the afformentioned nuget packages. Both of which i cannot find in the npm registry.

I need to find them, or i need a tutorial on how to implement a splash screen in a xamarin app, from inside visual studio 2015.

could anyone please help or provide a link or two...?

Comment: What does npm do here? They are components in Xamarin Components Store.

Comment: let me provide the link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/ - at the top under requirements, the two packages are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out, inside visual studio u need to go to the solution explorer for the project, right click on References, then click on Manage NuGet packages.

After this a tab with a search bar on the top will open.
Just type in AppCompat in the search bar and hit enter.

Pick the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat package and install it.
This will automatically install dependencies, including the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package.